# How to round results to nearest whole number - SQL

Tags: mysql

From my query below, I need to have the results listed to the nearest whole number, using the `ROUND` function.

```
Select dogs_id, Name,
POWER(money,2)/2 AS 'New Prize Money'
FROM DOG_EVENT
```

That runs fine, but one of the results comes up as 14.5, and I need that rounded to the nearest whole number.

Where and how can I add that to my query above, so that it rounds off to the nearest whole number?

Comment: You can use either CEIL() or FLOOR() funciton in MySQL mate. e.g. CEIL(POWER(money,2)/2) or FLOOR(POWER(money,2)/2) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's the part that is divided by 2

```
Select dogs_id, Name, ROUND(POWER(money,2)/2, 0) AS 'New Prize Money' FROM DOG_EVENT
```